# $X_i\sim \mathrm{UNIF}(0,\theta)$. Show that $S=X_{n:n}$ is sufficient for $\theta$ by the factorization criterion.

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics

> Consider a random sample from a uniform distribution $X_i\sim \mathrm{UNIF}(0,\theta)$, where $\theta$ is unknown. Show that $S=X_{n:n}$ is sufficient for $\theta$ by the factorization criterion.

> Factorization Criterion : 
> if $X_1,...,X_n$ have joint pdf $f(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)$ and if $S=(S_1,...,S_k)$, then $S_1,...,S_k$ are jointly sufficient for $\theta$ if and only if 
>
> $f(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)=g(s;\theta)h(x_1,...x_n)$

based on the questions, it is known that

$X_i\sim \mathrm{UNIF}(0,\theta)$ so the pdf is
$f(x) = 1/\theta$ , $0<=x<=\theta$

and the CDF is $F(x) = x/\theta$

> so, the joint pdf is
>
> $f(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)=f(x_1;\theta)...f(x_n;\theta)$
>
> $=(1/\theta)^n$ 
> $=1/\theta^n$ 
> $=g(x_{n:n};\theta)h(x_1,...,x_n)$
>
>
> where $=g(x_{n:n};\theta) =  g(s;\theta) =1/\theta^n$ if $s<\theta$ and zero otherwise, and $h(x_1,...,x_n) = 1$ if $0<x_{1:n}$ and zero otherwise. 
> So, $S=X_{n:n}$ is sufficient for $\theta$

But I don't understand why $g(x_{n:n};\theta) =  g(s;\theta) =1/\theta^n$?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the joint density needs to be specified completely.  A single observation has density
$$f_X(x \mid \theta) = \frac{1}{\theta} \mathbb 1(0 \le x \le \theta),$$ where $\mathbb 1$ is the indicator function
$$\mathbb 1 (0 \le x \le \theta) = \begin{cases}1 , & 0 \le x \le \theta \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$  So we have the joint density of $n$ iid observations
$$f_{\boldsymbol X}(x_1, \ldots, x_n \mid \theta) = \theta^{-n} \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1 (0 \le x_i \le \theta).$$  The product is equal to $1$ if and only if $$0 \le x_{1:n} \le x_{n:n} \le \theta,$$ that is to say, the smallest observation must be at least $0$ and the largest must not exceed $\theta$.  Hence the full joint density is
$$f_{\boldsymbol X}(x_1, \ldots, x_n \mid \theta) = \theta^{-n} \mathbb 1(x_{1:n} \ge 0) \mathbb 1(x_{n:n} \le \theta).$$
Now by the factorization theorem,
$$f = h(\boldsymbol x) g(T(\boldsymbol x) \mid \theta)$$
for the choice $h(\boldsymbol x) = \mathbb 1(x_{1:n} \ge 0)$, which does not depend on $\theta$; and $$g(T\mid \theta) = \theta^{-n} \mathbb 1(T \le \theta),$$ and $$T(\boldsymbol x) = x_{n:n}.$$  This last function $T$ is the sufficient statistic.